# Why when the text is scrolling up to the middle or near the end it's getting mess with many empty lines?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My code read a text file line by line and display them scroll them up inside a jquery newsTicker plugin.

The first in the beginning it's working good scrolling the lines no problems.
Somehwere in the middle more near the end it's getting mess many empty lines then many lines with only time and date.

This is the code i'm using:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://risq.github.io/jquery-advanced-news-ticker/assets/js/jquery.newsTicker.js"></script>
<style>
.newsticker {
    max-width: 620px;
    margin: auto;
}

.newsticker li {
    color: #4e4e4e;
    background: #F2F2F2;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 28px;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #2c8162;
}

.newsticker li:hover {
    background: #FFF;
}
</style>
<script>
   $('body').find('.newsticker').remove();//It will clear old data if its present 
   var file = "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/test.txt";
    $.get(file, function (txt) {
            //var lines = txt.responseText.split("\n");
            var lines = txt.split("\n");
            $ul = $('<ul class="newsticker" />');
            for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i+=3) {  // step: 3
                $ul.append('<li>' + lines[i] + '</li>'); //here 
                $ul.append('<li>' + lines[i+1] + '</li>');
            }
            //$ul.appendTo('body').newsTicker({
            $ul.appendTo('div.wcustomhtml').newsTicker({
                row_height: 48,
                max_rows: 10,
                speed: 600,
                direction: 'up',
                duration: 1000,
                autostart: 1,
                pauseOnHover: 1
            });
    });
</script>
```

Last changed were this:

```
for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i+=3) {  // step: 3
                    $ul.append('<li>' + lines[i] + '</li>'); //here 
                    $ul.append('<li>' + lines[i+1] + '</li>');
                }
```

And i changed the max_rows to 10 it was 2 but even when it was 2 somewhere sometimes it was getting mess.
You can see it on my site:

[My Test Site](http://newsxpressmedia.com/test.html)

First in the beginning it's working a line then under it a line with date and time and they are all scrolling up.
But if you wait a bit you will see after 20-30 seconds or less that's it's getting mess lines empty some lines with date and time only.

Not sure why it happen like that when it's getting to the middle or near the end of reading the text file.

This is the complete text file content the text is in hebrew but this is the how it looks like the format:

[Text File Content](http://textuploader.com/rl78)

The problem is that somewhere after scrolling the text the lines it's getting mess.

Comment: Because in your text file at http://textuploader.com/rl78 there are empty lines. I don't really speak this language, but go down to the line that says "דווח במקור בתאריך: 02.04.14  שעה : 13:39" below it there is an empty space which is tripping your plugin up.

Comment: Right thanks i will fixthe text file format creation so the content will have one empty line between each two lines. Thanks.